# Why is the square of a normal matrix as well a normal matrix?

Tags: matrices

Or is it? Be $A$ a normal matrix and my question is if $A^2$ is as well a normal matrix?

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition?

Answer (score 2):

A matrix $A$ is normal iff $AA^*=A^*A$. If $A$ is normal, then
$$A^2(A^2)^*=A^2(A^*)^2=AAA^*A^*=AA^*AA^*=A^*AAA^*=A^*AA^*A=A^*A^*AA=(A^2)^*A^2$$
thus $A^2$ is normal as well.